# Lodash Nested Loop Search

Tags: javascript, lodash

How would I go about writing the following nested loop in `lodash`? What would be the tersest, *and hopefully more semantic*, syntax?

```
for (var i = 0, m = 0, inner, item, needle = 'someval'; i < items.length; i++) {
    item = items[i];

    for (m = 0; m < item.inners.length; m++) {
        inner = item.inners[m];

        if (inner.id === needle)
            return { items : item.id };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it would be something like

```
var item = _.find(items, function(item) {
  return _.some(item.inners, { id: needle });
});
```

This reads like "find the item which has at least one inners element with id equal to needle".

See [`_.find`](https://lodash.com/docs#find) and [`_.some`](https://lodash.com/docs#some).

If you can use ES6:

```
let item = items.find(({inners}) => inners.some(({id}) => id === needle));
```

Comment: the first version won't terminate until ***all*** items have been compared. will the ES6 version terminate early? would like it to be as performant as possible ... +1

Comment: What makes you think that? Both find and some stop as soon as the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: `_.find` returns as soon as the predicate evaluates to true, doesn't it?

Comment: bah, you're right. just saw that. thanks @FelixKling!